# Find the number of instructions of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given this algorithm (a>0, b>0) :

```
while(a>=b){
   k=1;
   while(a>=k*b){
      a = a - k*b;
      k++;
   }
}
```

**My question** : I have to find the time complexity of this algorithm and to do so, I must find the number of instructions but I couldn't find it. Is there a way to find this number and if not, how can I find its time complexity ?

**What I have done** : First of all I tried to find the number of iterations of the first loop and I found a pattern : a_i = a - (i(i+1)/2)*b where i is the number of iterations. I've spent hours doing some manipulations on it but I couldn't find anything relevant (I've found weird results like q² <= a/b < q²+q where q is the number of iterations).

Comment: Edit : I forgot to add the k++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly calculated that the value of `a` after the `i`-th iteration of the inner loop is:

[image]

Where `a_j0` is the value of `a` at the start of the `j`-th outer loop. The stopping condition for the inner loop is:

[image]

Which can be solved as a quadratic inequality:

[image]

Therefore the inner loop is approximately `O(sqrt(a_j0 / b))`. The *next* starting value of `a` satisfies:

[image]

Scaling roughly as `sqrt(2b * a_j0)`. It would be quite tedious to compute the  time complexity exactly, so let's apply the above approximations from here on:

[image]

Where `a_n` replaces `a_j0`, and `t_n` is the run-time of the inner loop – and of course the total time complexity is just the sum of `t_n`. Note that the first term is given by `n = 1`, and that the input value of `a` is defined to be `a_0`.

Before directly solving this recurrence, note that since the second term `t_2` is already proportional to the square root of the first `t_1`, the latter dominates all other terms in the sum.

> The total time complexity is therefore just **`O(sqrt(a / b))`**.

---

Update: numerical tests.

Note that, since all changes in the value of `a` are proportional to `b`, and all loop conditions are also proportional to `b`, the function can be **"normalized"** by setting `b = 1` and only varying `a`.

Javascript test function, which measures the number of times that the inner loop executes:

```
function T(n)
{
   let t = 0, k = 0;
   while (n >= 1) {
      k = 1;
      while (n >= k) {
          n -= k;
          k++; t++;
      }
   }
   return t;
}
```

Plot of `sqrt(n)` against `T(n)`:

[image]

A convincing straight line which confirms that the time complexity is indeed half-power.