# Time complexity of an algorithm with two nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given this algorithm :

```
m = 1
while(a>m*b){
   m = m*2
}

while(a>=b){
   while(a>=m*b){
      a = a-m*b
   }
   m=m/2
}
```

**My question** : What is the time complexity of this algorithm ?

**What I have done** : I have to find the number of instructions. So I found out that, for the first while, there is m=log_2(a/b) iterations approximately. Now for the inner while of the second part of this algorithm, I found this pattern : a_i = a - i*m where i is the number of iterations. So there is a/bm iterations for the inner while.
But I don't know how to calculate the outer now because the condition depends on what the inner while have done to a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's begin by **"normalizing"** the function in the same way as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797089/find-the-number-of-instructions-of-an-algorithm), noting that once again all changes in `a` and stopping conditions are proportional to `b`:

```
n = a/b

// 1)
m = 1
while(n>m){
   m = m*2
}

// 2)
while(n>=1){
   while(n>=m){
      n = n-m
   }
   m=m/2
}
```

Unfortunately, this is where the similarity ends...

---

**Snippet 1)**

Note that `m` can be written as an integer power of 2, since it doubles every loop:

```
i = 0
while (n > pow(2, i)) {
   i++
}
// m = pow(2, i)
```

From the stopping condition:

[image]

---

**Snippet 2)**

Here `m` decreases in the exact opposite way to **1)**, so it can again be written as a power of 2:

```
// using i from the end of 1)
while (n>=1) {
   k = pow(2, i)
   while (n >= k) {
      n = n - k
   }
   i--
}
```

The inner loop is simpler than the inner loop from your previous question, because `m` does not change inside it. It is easy to deduce the number of times `c` it executes, and the value of `n` at the end:

[image]

This is the exact definition of the [Modulus operator `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524673/understanding-the-modulus-operator) in the "C-family" of languages:

```
while (n>=1) {
   k = pow(2, i)
   n = n % k      // time complexity O(n / k) here instead of O(1)
   i--
}
```

Note that, because consecutive values of `k` only differ by a factor of 2, at no point will the value of `n` be greater than or equal to `2k`; this means that the inner loop executes *at most once* per outer loop. Therefore the outer loop executes *at most* `i` *times*.

> Both the first and second loops are `O(log n)`, which means the total time complexity is **`O(log n) = O(log [a/b])`**.

---

Update: numerical tests in Javascript as before.

```
function T(n)
{
   let t = 0;

   let m = 1;
   while (n > m) {
      m *= 2; t++;
   }

   while (n >= 1) {
      while (n >= m) {
         n -= m; t++;
      }
      m/=2;
   }

   return t;
}
```

Plotting `T(n)` against `log(n)` shows a nice straight line:

[image]

---

Edit: a more thorough explanation of snippet **2)**.

At the end of snippet **1)**, the value of `i = ceil(log2(n))` represents the *number of significant bits* in the binary representation of the integer `ceil(n)`.

Computing the modulus of an integer with a positive power-of-2 `2^i` is equivalent to *discarding* all but the first `i` bits. For example:

```
n     = ...00011111111   (binary)
m     = ...00000100000   (= 2^5)
n % m = ...00000011111
                 -----   (5 least significant bits)
```

The operation of snippet **2)** is therefore equivalent to removing the most significant bit of `n`, one at a time, until only zero is left. For example:

```
 outer loop no |           n
 ----------------------------
 1             | ...110101101
               |    ^
 2             | ...010101101
               |     ^
 3             | ...000101101
               |      ^
 4             | ...000001101
               |       ^ 
 :             | :
 :             | :
 i (=9)        | ...000000001
               |            ^
 ----------------------------
 final         |    000000000
```

When the current most significant bit (pointed to by `^`) is:

- **0**: the inner loop does *not* execute because the value of `n` is already smaller than `k = 2^i` (equal to the bit position value of `^`).
- **1**: the inner loop executes *once* because `n` is greater than `k`, but less than `2k` (which corresponds the bit above the current position `^`).

Hence the "worst" case occurs when all significant bits of `n` are 1, in which case the inner loop to always executes once.

Regardless, the outer loop executes `ceil(log2(n))` times for *any* value of `n`.